# C++ Constructor Exception Handling

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I am new to exception handling in C++, and recently I ran into a bit of an issue.

In my code I want to create an object and only one of them.  I am interfacing with a library where I must provide inputs to the constructor.  Here's what a call to the constructor would look like:

```
ObjectA my_object(param1, param2, param3);
```

My issue is that the constructor itself can throw exceptions.  I have done limited work with exceptions in the past (I know about the try-catch mechanism), but I'm not sure what to do here due to variable scope.  For example:

```
try {
  ObjectA my_object(param1, param2, param3);
}
catch {
  // don't worry I need to do more than this here, just an example...
  cout << "OMFG!" << endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// if code got here, everything with my_object is OK
my_object.Method1(param1);  // ERROR: my_object is out of scope!
```

Some help would be appreciated in a quick way that I can check for the object being constructed correctly.  Thanks

Comment: Put everything related to the object inside the try block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, like this:

```
try {
  ObjectA my_object(param1, param2, param3);
  my_object.Method1(param1);
  // other work
}
catch (/* the exception that constructor can throw */ ){
   // error handling stuff
}
```

If the `try` block would be to big, move the code from it to another function.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of actions is small, sometimes you do this:

```
try {
    ObjectA my_object(param1, param2, param3);
    my_object.Method1(param1);
}catch(...)
{exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
```

Commonly, if the constructor can throw exceptions, there exists an alternative way to initailize without exceptions:

```
ObjectA my_object; //may or may not be valid by itself 
try {
    my_object = ObjectA(param1, param2, param3); //initialize and copy-construct
    //alternatively:
    my_object.open(param1, param2, param3);
}catch(...)
{exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
my_object.Method1(param1);
```

Otherwise, the most recommended solution is this:

```
boost::optional<ObjectA> my_object; //make it OPTIONAL
try {
    my_object = ObjectA(param1, param2, param3); //initialize and copy-construct
}catch(...)
{exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
my_object.Method1(param1);
```

(if you don't like boost, `optional` is pretty trivial to implement yourself if you know how placement new works)

If the optional thing is too intimidated, it's easily replicated via dynamic memory as well:

```
std::unique_ptr<ObjectA> my_object; //make it OPTIONAL
try {
    my_object.reset(new ObjectA(param1, param2, param3)); //initialize and copy-construct
}catch(...)
{exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
my_object->Method1(param1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void doStuff()
{
  ObjectA my_object(param1, param2, param3);
  my_object.Method1(param1); 
}

try {
  doStuff();
}
catch {
  // don't worry I need to do more than this here, just an example...
  cout << "OMFG!" << endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

or simply put all the relevant statements inside the try block.